# Yaml List to Parameter to Vector

Tags: rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've been trying to store a list of doubles in a yaml file, load it into the parameter server, and later pull it back out from the server into a std::vector in a cpp file, on ROS Kinetic.

yaml syntax I've used:

```
param_name:       [ .546, -.546, -.546,  .546,  .724, .724]
```

I've been able to get the list up into the parameter server without issue (currently, just via a 'rosparam load' terminal command on the yaml file). 'rosparam get' commands in the terminal return the expected values from it once it's there. However, when I try to retrieve the parameter within the cpp file I run into issues:

```
std::vector<double> param_list
if( !nh_.getParam("/param_name", param_list) )
    ROS_ERROR("Failed to get parameter from server.");
```

compiles, publishes the error message and fails to populate the vector. I've had confusing issues in the past dealing with ambiguous ros parameter server types so I've also tried this with a vector of floats with the same result. I think that the syntax I've used on the retrieval end matches that demonstrated here: http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#CA-a03bfcab2d7595a784e24298b326fdc4c76f3aee_5

Do I have to do something to explicitly cast the data as the right type when I load it into the parameter server from the yaml?

I've also been able to get the XmlRpc method demonstrated in the above link to work with the vector - partly. I can retrieve the data and assert the list itself to be an array:

```
XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue param_list;
if( !nh_.getParam("/param_name", param_list) )
    ROS_ERROR("Still failed...");
ROS_ASSERT(param_list.getType() == XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::TypeArray);
```

but when I try to assert the values in the array to be doubles:

```
for (int32_t i = 0; i < param_list.size(); ++i) 
{
  ROS_ASSERT(param_list[i].getType() == XmlRpc::XmlRpcValue::TypeDouble);
}
```

I get an "assertion failed" error on running the program. If I output the values in the array they seem correct even when not asserted to be doubles, but I get compile errors about "ambiguity" when I try to assign them to another, non-XmlRpc value later on. Either way though I'd really rather avoid using XmlRpc at all if I can make the vector stuff work instead!

In the past I've had similar setups work, pulling data out of a yaml file to the parameter server and then into a cpp file, but haven't ever been able to get yaml lists to cpp vectors to work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262089/yaml-list-to-parameter-to-vector/) by [conor.mcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/28529/conor.mcmahon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2017-05-18

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your retrieval methods look correct, meaning it's most likely a problem with the parameter itself. This may be inconsequential, but try putting a zero in front of your decimal values, rather than starting with the period. My code looks identical to yours, but I use zeros in the parameters.

---

Originally posted by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) with karma: 885 on 2017-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [conor.mcmahon](https://answers.ros.org/users/28529/conor.mcmahon/) on 2017-05-18**:
Wow, it looks like this did it, thanks!! Just made this change and it works as expected now.

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-05-18**:
Yeah sometimes it's the little things... Glad I could help!